# How can I map out a series of characters into an upside-down pyramid using a loop?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I have a task of mapping out this:

```
* * * * *
 * * * *
  * * *
   * *
    *
```

(notice the spacing), by using a loop(preferably for loop), for a set number of n. example above: $n=5;

This is my latest attempt:

```
$n=5;
for ($i=0; $i < $n ; $i++) { 

 for ($j=0; $j <= $i ; $j++) { 
     echo "&nbsp;";
 }

 for ($k=0; $k < $n ; $k++) { 
    echo " * ";
 }
 echo "<br>";
}
```

I want to add something that can reduce n, like n--;, and then print out 1 less "*".

Comment: Can you post at least one of the many things you tried (in your question)? And where it fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just start at the maximum number of stars and decrement the counter.  The maximum minus the current number will give the number of leading spaces needed:

```
$n = 5;
for($i=$n; $i>0; $i--) {
    echo str_repeat(' ' , $n-$i) . str_repeat('* ', $i) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

I use `str_repeat`, you can use a loop if you want.  Also, to render in HTML replace the spaces with `&nbsp;` and `PHP_EOL` with `<br />`:

```
$n = 5;
for($i=$n; $i>0; $i--) {
    echo str_repeat('&nbsp;' , $n-$i) . str_repeat('*&nbsp;', $i) . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should theoretically work:

```
$space = 0;
$stars = 5;

for($i = 0; $i < 5;$i++){
    echo str_repeat(" ",$space);
    echo str_repeat("* ",$stars);
    $space++;
    $stars--;
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
* * * * *
 * * * *
  * * *
   * *
    *
```

Answer (score 1):

This builds the longest line by repeating `*` for the number your after.  It also sets a padding to `""` to start.  Then each loop it just adds an extra space to the padding and takes the last 2 characters off the output line (using `substr()`)...

```
$n = 5;
$output = str_repeat("* ", $n);
$pad = "";
for ( $i = 0; $i < $n; $i++ )   {
    echo $pad.$output.PHP_EOL;
    $pad .= " ";
    $output = substr($output, 0, -2);
}
```

gives (note this is in ascii and not HTML)...

```
* * * * * 
 * * * * 
  * * * 
   * * 
    *
```

to use HTML, change the `PHP_EOL` to `<br>` and the space to `&nbsp;`